# Guitar versus electronic keyboard workstation

Tags: guitar, learning, keyboard

Between a guitar and an electronic keyboard workstation, which one takes less time and/or effort to become proficient with just for singing privately in my home with my family?

(for an absolute beginner)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guitar is much more challenging at first for several reasons:

The first is the instrument itself. If it is not a good one or at least one that is set up properly it can be very difficult to get a good sound initially because of strings being too high or stiff or the neck not being adjusted properly.

Next is the fact that guitar requires both hands coordinated properly to produce one sound. With the keyboard each hand is capable of producing sound on its own although it still requires coordination between the two of them.

Another reason is the movement and pressing of notes with the left hand (for a right handed player) of the guitar is very difficult for most to achieve at first. Some people give up in frustration after a short time because of this and also because they don’t have the physical strength initially to hold down the notes. They can also be discouraged by pain in the fingertips when trying to hold down the strings until their fingertips toughen up after a while.

Piano on the other hand is practically effortless at first, you press a key, you hear a sound. It is easier to advance at a very basic level than the guitar because you don’t have the same types of physical challenges.

All that being said there are millions of people who learn both instruments and enjoy playing them for a lifetime and there are millions who quit in frustration after a few days, weeks, or months.

My point is not to dissuade you from playing the guitar, my point is to make you aware of the fact that guitar will be tougher initially so you know what to expect. As you begin to develop finger strength and coordination your learning will begin to snowball.

Both instruments are perfectly capable for what your goals are so you should ultimately choose the one that appeals to you more and whose sound you are more drawn towards.

Comment: We'd have to disagree about both hands on guitar. Once a chord shape has been established with the fretting hand, it's not too onerous to mindlessly strum the strings with the other!

Comment: @Tim Mindlessly? Yes we will have to disagree about that. For someone like you that has been doing it for decades strumming might be mindless. For someone starting out it can be and often is difficult at first. First it takes time to learn to strum the correct number of strings for different chords. Once they get past steady strumming,  simple strumming patterns divide their concentration between moving the LH fingers and playing a combination of down and down-up strums with quarter notes and eighth notes in the RH. There’s nothing mindless about that if you don’t already know how to do it!

Comment: As a beginner, I felt it necessary to play all strings for all chords, thus learnt shapes that way. And still do often play all 6 strings, regardless of so many sites telling that each chord must be in root position. Which still doesn't have a ring of truth about it! Open D was the only one that caused problems. Just re-looked up 'strum' in Oxford dictionary - 'to play in an instrument carelessly or unskilfully' - knew I'd seen it somewhere!

Comment: @Tim I looked up the lyrics to Stairway to Heaven and found "Cause you know, sometimes words have two meanings". If you play all 6 strings carelessly, that doesn't mean it's all there is to the style guitarists call strumming.

Comment: @ojs - you didn't need to look as far as 'Stairway' - consider 'hard' and 'light', for starters, 
 - nevertheless, I still consider guitar as the easier start up, particularly for OP's aims, having taught both.

Comment: @Tim yes, I'm aware that you teach guitar and that's why I'm constantly surprised that you're unaware of guitar-related vocabulary and look at Oxford dictionary instead of any instrument-specific text.

Comment: @Tim “…I felt it necessary to play all strings…” Why? Because it was easier? You have always disdained playing the root on the bottom of open guitar chords here on MPT. Just because you can play an E below A shape chords or a G below C shape chords doesn’t mean it’s better. Unless you’re intentionally playing inversions, open guitar chords with the root on the bottom sound cleaner. The P4 interval at the bottom with the 5th in the bass is muddy sounding. If you were voicing a chord for an orchestra or band I doubt you would start with ^5-^1 on the bottom so why do it on guitar?

Comment: @ojs I don’t have a copy of the Oxford dictionary but I would like to assume that that is only part of the definition of strumming. If not they need to revamp their music department. I wonder what great rhythm guitarists like John Lennon and Nile Rogers would think of that.

Comment: I guess at the time, I felt I'd been given 6 strings, so 6 strings were to be played. In bands at 14yo. the bass would play roots, so on gtr I could play whatever inversion I wanted. In orchestrations or big band arrangements, certainly not every chord is root-based - that would get quite boring to listen to - and play, for the whole band or gtr, granted, In fact,2 or 3 notes now suffice.But for a beginner, on their own, I've never found it to be a problem. Better or not? Just different. I must listen to rhythm players to find out exactly what they actually do!But doubt if all chords are root.

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard the theory that it takes 10,000 hours<sup>[1]</sup> to become fully proficient with any skill - be it musicianship, cooking or carpentry.

It's about right.
There are no shortcuts.

You could learn to thump out a few simple chords on either in a couple of weeks, if that's all you need, but don't expect to be really any good at all for at least a year, depending on your practise regime.

<sup>[1]</sup>This isn't an absolute truth, but it's close enough to be good 'shorthand' for "there are no shortcuts to acquiring a skill".
See [The National Library of Medicine - The 10,000-hour rule](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4662388/) for the origins of this theory.

Answer (score 0):

As you'll just be accompanying people singing, a few chords (initially) will get you going, so my money's on guitar (I play both). Learning to strum is fairly fundamental, whereas with a keyboard, you'll need to learn not only which keys to press, but the timing at which to press them, to sound convincing.